# PHP simple upload script missing input field. Why?

Tags: php, input, field

I'm working through some examples in a book (Learning PHP, MySQL, JavaScript, and CSS 2nd Ed) and have the following code copied verbatim from the book which pictures the result showing an input field. When I run the script, the upload feature works, but I'm missing the input field. Why? I can't seem to find any solutions when searching Google. Is this an error in the book??

Here's the code:

```
<?php // upload.php
echo <<<_END
<html><head><title>PHP Form Upload</title></head><body>
<form method='post' action='upload.php' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
Select File: <input type='file' name='filename' size='10' />
<input type='submit' value='Upload' />
</form>
_END;

if ($_FILES)
{
$name = $_FILES['filename']['name'];
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], $name);
echo "Uploaded image '$name'<br /><img src='$name' />";
}
echo "</body></html>";
?>
```

EDIT - Here is the pictured result from the book: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OrEzt.jpg

Comment: What kind of input is shown there? What should it do? And, in this code here is only a sumbit and a "files" button.

Comment: According to the screenshot in the book, there should be a input field with a browse button next to it, but for some reason I think it was left out of the code example.

Comment: @Chip: What you're describing is an `input type="file"`, which is in this code.  Is that input not showing up in your page?

Comment: Here's a shot of what shows up for me in both Chrome and FF:  http://i.imgur.com/TwDKz3Q.jpg

Comment: I see the input field in that image. Also you stated "When I run the script, the upload feature works" - it wouldn't work without the input field being there. What is it you are expecting to see?

Comment: I was expecting to see the text input field shown in this screenshot from the book: http://i.imgur.com/h4rEVWU.jpg

Comment: Please burn this book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the following:

[HTML input type="file" in Chrome does not show textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5260747/html-input-type-file-in-chrome-does-not-show-textbox)

And the provided solution:
http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html

It looks like some modern browsers choose not to render a textbox for input type="file". If you want or need the textbox, then the second link has a solution in javascript

Comment: Thank you. This is the straightforward answer I was looking for to clear up my confusion. Since I'm in the process of learning PHP, I have an itch to fill in any knowledge gaps and this one was bothering me even though it seems trivial. :)