# HTML input type=“file” in Google Chrome not showing popup window

Tags: html, forms, google-chrome, input

I'm having a problem with the HTML tag `<input type="file" />` in Google Chrome.

The 'Browse' button appears on the page as expected, but when I click it in order to select a file, the pop-up dialog window from the browser doesn't open at all.

I 've tested my form and in Firefox and works correct. Any ideas what's wrong and how can I fix it ?

Here is also the code:

```
<form action="" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="imgfile">File input</label>
<input type="file" name="imgfile" />
```

Comment: input should be in `<form>` tag

Comment: I can't replicate this on the latest version of Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/j43C3

Comment: @Orlo That shouldn't make a difference. The dialog box should appear irrespective of the presence of form tag

Comment: I believe your answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5260747/html-input-type-file-in-chrome-does-not-show-textbox

Comment: Also if your issue is with clicking the `label` element to make the dialog appear, this works in Chrome if you change `name` to `id` on the `input` element: http://jsfiddle.net/j43C3/1/.

Comment: Works for me in Jsfiddle.

Comment: @James Donnelly: neither in the link you gave opens! Is this some kind of setting I have to do in Chrome?

Comment: @Lykos sounds like it might be some plugin you have interfering with the element.

Comment: Use Window->Extensions to see all the extensions you have loaded.

Comment: The only plugins I have are: colorzilla and skype. I have deactivate them though and test it again, but same result.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no reason that this shouldn't work in Chrome. Have you tried copying JUST the mark up in the example you've given us into a HTML file, and opening that? Does it work? It should, unless there's some third party plugin or extension stopping it.

It may be that you have have mark up elsewhere causing this issue; perhaps a layer over the input field catching the click event before it can make it's way down to the "browse" button?

Comment: It seems that a plugin (Colorzila), that I had installed on Chrome, was stopping it. I deactivated it, restart the Chrome and worked eventually.

Comment: Good to know! I'll keep an eye out for that in future. Thanks for feeding back.

Comment: The same problem happened to me. I disabled all my plugins, restarted chrome, and it worked again. However, when I re-enabled all my plugins and restarted chrome, it was still working. Very odd!

Comment: A good way to test which plugin/plugins cause this is to disable one at a time, each time and test it. Still very odd though, since in firefox haven't occured this (yet).

Comment: in my case I was cancelling the click events for a popup menu, so I had to change to check e.target.type !== 'file'

Comment: Removing Colorzilla and restarting chrome seemed to do the trick for me too. Thanks @ltdev.

Comment: @oomer it was restarting chrome that did the trick. Colorzilla is not to blame here. This issue has been popping up across unrelated browsers. https://stackoverflow.com/a/69690942 This answer addresses the issue properly and it seems to be a practice all browser vendors have adopted

Answer (score 75):

This happened to me on Chrome v88.0, and I tried everything -- removing all the event handlers, making the simplest form possible, removing all other html and js from the page -- and still the file-selection dialog would not appear when clicking the "Choose File" button.

Then I shut down Chrome and re-opened it ... and it worked again.

Golden advice:

> Have you tried turning it off and on again?

Comment: save my day - thx

Comment: Save my day, but curious what's the issue here?

Comment: For me also same. I simply had to restart Chrome Browser, after nearly 30 minutes of skimming through code to find out the part that could cause this problem!!!!

Comment: @VishweshJainkuniya, I think, I know why! After restarting chrome, I opened the browser console for development reason. I was presented with Google Chrome Updated message. May be this could have caused the issue. Chrome updated in the background & that could have prevented the file dialog box getting opened.

Comment: But how chrome update is related to this?
In anyway chrome updates won't be applied until chrome is restarted, so it should work as it as it was on previous version, right?

Comment: This was the issue for me too.

Comment: Wow, this solved it for me too! Thanks!!!

Comment: So the chrome update fixed it for me. This is quite interesting as @VishweshJainkuniya pointed out the chrome update shouldn't be applied until restart. That makes me wonder if some underlying protocol has changed that they were relying on.

Comment: @Niklas looks like an attempt by browser vendors to ensure that people update their browsers. Break all sites so user restarts browser, apply downloaded browser update during restart

Comment: Solid advice! I wonder what happened

Comment: Indeed o.O Restarting Brave/Chrome did the trick! But...why? (?)

Comment: Recycled answer from below

Comment: Holly sh*t, f**k it, i've spent a half of a day debugging why  file-input doesn't open file modal. After all I tried to check in Safari, and OMG, it works as it should. And after that I read that it was needed just to relaunch Chome app xDDD

Comment: After all, thank you for this working solution :)

Answer (score 20):

In my case the problem was as follows :

1. Whole document had a "on click handler"
2. Inside click hander, the code was canceling all propagation with

   return false;

Removing this return statement solved problem with input=file.

Comment: Bingo. Thank you.

Comment: My problem was similar except it was a case of event.preventDefault() being called. It seems the click event propagates to all event handlers, and then the default action happens if it has not been prevented. I had assumed incorrectly that the child's default action would occur before the event propagated to the parent.

Comment: you save me thank you very much

Comment: scenario: you have a div (D1) outer and have a div (D2) inner. both have onclick handlers. if you cancel click events of D1 by stop propagation etc,  and click on D2, this click is NOT blocked because click handler of D2 (inner) is triggered earlier than D1. But for the input type=file things change, if you add input type=file in D2, and click on it, popup will never shown.

Comment: Bingo, thanks for the reminder. Turned out I had another click even handler that wasn't specific enough and thus also governed the click event on the input, effectively returning false because the input lacked a required attribute.

Answer (score 11):

I knew the problem wasn't an issue with the specific web page I was currently browsing because I went to codepen and tried various file uploaders to no avail.

In my specific scenario, I had run a chrome update a few days ago but failed to relaunch chrome after the update.

Navigating to Help > About Google Chrome, Google had informed me that a relaunch was necessary.

After relaunch, the browser native file picker started appearing again.

Comment: Fixed for me as well. Thanks! Saved me from investigating a nonexistent bug.

Comment: Thanks, I was so deep into solving this problem, and found this. Just restart Chrome!

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue, it would work in safari but not chrome. Turns out I just needed to update my chrome browser. Apparently if your chrome version is out of date by two weeks functionality that has been around for over a decade breaks...you know google engineering at its finest...

Comment: Thanks!!! I spent days (not hours) with this stupid limitation.

Comment: Suddenly Browse button didn't work in Chrome but Safari. After updating chrome version, It started to work properly.

Comment: Is there any way we can detect programatically when this issue is happening? Does the browser throw any error or give an indication that the input button has been disabled? Can programmers check if the `<input type="file"/>` is working before loading it?

Comment: Also it looks like an attempt by all browser vendors to ensure that people update their browsers because I've seen this issue happen in Firefox too. Approach seems to be this: Break all sites so user restarts browser, apply downloaded browser update during restart.

Answer (score 5):

There could be two reasons for the input type file not working.

1. The file type input is styled as visibility: hidden. To hide the input use opacity:0.
2. There may be click event on document or parent element resisting click on input tag.

Answer (score 5):

I had same issue recently. Restarting chrome fixed it.
Go to [chrome://restart](https://chrome://restart) to do it.

Comment: Typical "Did you try turning it off and on again?" 

This solved it for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that a plugin (Colorzila), that I had installed on Chrome, was stopping it. I deactivated it, restart the Chrome and worked eventually.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, vendor css was having a default CSS written to hide the input type file to display: none, as shown below, removing that/overriding that, made browse to work as expected. Hope it may help, that to verify if css for input[type='file'] is driven from other places.

```
//remove the below code
input[type="file"] {
 display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a global event event listener on `window`:

```js
window.addEventListener("click", event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Of course this was stopping my input from reacting. Be careful with global or local listeners that do `preventDefault()`

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me

```
<input type="file" id="fileProfile2" name="fileProfile2"  accept="image/png,image/jpeg"  >
```

Comment: lol, you have a opening tag `input` and a closing tag `label` xd

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where I was hiding the `input` element and trying to trigger the popup when a user clicked on the form label.

In my case, the `for` attribute on the label element didn't match the `id` of the input. Once I updated the `for` on the label to match the input's `id` the popup window worked great.

Simple Example:

```html
  <form>
    <label for="images">Click here to upload your images!</label>
    <input id="images" type="file" accept="images/*" style="display:none;" />
  </form>
```

I found it difficult to style the input itself, so I hid the actual input element and styled the label to look like a file upload input.

Now whenever someone clicks on the label element the file popup will appear even though the input element is hidden.

Answer (score 0):

I set event.preventDefault() in ajax request that is why input value was not being sent in form data

Answer (score -1):

You must use it like this

```
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    .......
    .......
    <label for="imgfile">File input</label>
    <input type="file" name="imgfile" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
```

Comment: If I read the OP right. This isn't the problem. The problems is that the popup windows won't open. Not the problem of uploading files.

Answer (score -1):

Hope it helps someone; in my case the issue was that I had `event.preventDefault()` applying to the whole document, because I had my eventListener applying to the whole document:

```js
function onMouse( event ) {

 event.preventDefault();
 
 // calculate mouse position in normalized device coordinates
 // (-1 to +1) for both components

 mouse.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
 mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;
 
 mouseEventHandler( event );
 
}

document.addEventListener( 'click', onMouse, false );
```

I only wanted my custom event handlers to apply to one div, not to the whole document, and specifically I didn't want my event handlers overriding the form events, set up in another div. So I limited the scope of my eventListeners to the 'visualizationContainer' div:

`document.getElementByID('visualizationContainer').addEventListener( 'click', onMouse, false );`

That fixed everything.

Comment: 'mouse is not defined'

Answer (score -1):

Observed Symptoms: The "Choose File" button (from the input type=file html tag) does not pop a file selection dialog. Same web page works on Firefox (version 68.5.0) on the same device.

Answer: Use Firefox on Android if the failure to select a file for upload symptoms appear. The code below does work on Linux Chrome (version 80.0.3987.87). It also works on Windows 10 Chrome (version 80.0.3987.122). This seems to only apply to Android and likely only certain versions.

Hardware: LG-H812 
Android version: 6.0
Chrome version: 80.0.3987.117

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang = "en">
    <head>
        <title>t9.php</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>t9.php</h1>

        <form method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
            <input type='file' name='filename'/><br>
            <br>
            <input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit'/><br>
            <br>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

happened to me when trying to upload a 2GB file locally (e.g. `Photos Library.photoslibrary`)