# HTML Form file chooser not opening on Chrome

Tags: html, forms, bootstrap-4

I have this form on my website:

```
<form method="post" id="insert_station_form">
  <label>Title</label>
  <input type="text" name="title" id="title" class="form-control" />
  <br />
  <label>Subtitle</label>
  <input type="text" name="subtitle" id="subtitle" class="form-control" />
  <br />
  <label>Radio Url</label>
  <input type="text" name="aurl" id="aurl" class="form-control" />
  <br />
  <label>Radio Logo</label>
  <input type="text" name="logo_url" id="logo_url" class="form-control" />
  <br />
  <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload"/>
  <br />
  <br />
  <input type="submit" name="insert" id="insert" value="Insert" class="btn btn-success" />
</form>
```

I'm facing a problem that in Chrome the file upload chooser not showing up, but in Firefox and Safari it's opened and working fine, Any idea what is the problem?

EDIT

---

I also try this:

```
https://jsfiddle.net/dygsj6p7/
```

And it's not open the file dialog in chrome.

Comment: Check this out. Little bit of search: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22245500/html-input-type-file-in-google-chrome-not-showing-popup-window

Comment: @MaciejGromadzki I checked this post already, I remove my extensions and still not working. also tried to check on incognito and not working as well.

Comment: Have you tried to add ```enctype="multipart/form-data"``` to your form?

Comment: @MaciejGromadzki Yes i already try this

Comment: @MaciejGromadzki I just update my code

Comment: is your Chrome up to date? This has to be problem with your browser. Try to uninstall Chrome (all files) and install again. Tell me if help.

Answer (score 72):

I had the same problem where the syntax of my code was correct and the dialogue opened on Safari but not Chrome. It's likely a problem with your version of chrome.

Try going to **chrome://restart** in your browser, that fixed it for me.

Comment: chrome://restart worked for me also. I wonder what the problem is....

Comment: In my case, it was a download that got hung up, somehow. (It was failing to open on all websites.)

Comment: Thanks chrome://restart worked for me.

Comment: Works like a charm. But any clues how this solution works?

Comment: I have the same problem for MacOs Chrome Version 106.0.5249.91 (2022) - restart helps - thank you

Comment: I encountered the same issue several times recently for MAC Monterey(12.2) with Chrome Version 106.0.5249.119 (Official Build) (arm64) 
I have to enter chrome://restart once in a while

Comment: Worked for me as well. Thanks!

Can someone know how can I prevent it from happening in the future though? Is it a chrome-related bug and that's it? Or there is a way to avoid it programmatically?

Comment: Worked for me on macOS Monterey 12.0.1 and Chrome Version 110.0.5481.177 (Official Build) (arm64). It's odd that this seems to be an intermittent issue for me.

Comment: Lol. Try turning it off and on again.